# Apache basic auth with IP whitelist

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I am trying to add some kind of IP whitelist to one of my HTTP Basic Auth protected directories. I am using Apache 2.2.15 on CentOS 6.5 but I also tried with Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 10.04.

I looked at the apache wiki for an example: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/BypassAuthenticationOrAuthorizationRequirements

My configuration looks like the following:

```
<Location "/auth-test">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Auth-Test"
  AuthUserFile /tmp/htpasswd
  Require valid-user
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from 192.168.1.111
  Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

The IP 192.168.1.111 is my IP but the server still asks me for a password.

Comment: Double check Apache access log to make sure that Apache really sees that IP when you connect.

Comment: And confirm that you don't have a prior `.htaccess` file sitting in that directory either.